# garbled text after echo with color

Tags: 18.04, bash

I installed brand new Ubuntu 18.04. Open Terminal, and copy

echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"

from https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

[image]

Why does echo color text output garbled text?

Comment: It's working fine in my system. Have you changed default shell? What is the output of `echo $SHELL; echo $BASH_VERSION`?

Comment: After your fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, did you run the commands `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?